# How to use the type 'Type'

Tags: c#, types

I know that I can use the type `string` as:

```
string someString = "This is my string";
```

I am not sure how to use the type `Type`

```
Type someType = someString.GetType();
```

How could I create a variable based on that type. I want to do something like

```
someType someOtherString = "here is another string";
//string
```

In other words, how could I create a variable based on some type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about this, but the simplest would be to use the Activator class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx

Example:

```
Type t = someClassInstance.GetType();
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Answer (score 2):

Variable types have to be known at declaration time. You can declare a variable of type `object` and then dynamically create an instance of a type which you only know about at execution time, but you can't dynamically declare a variable like that.

The closest you could get would be to create a generic type and instantiate that using a type argument specified with reflection. Then you really would have a variable of the right type - but you wouldn't be able to do anything particularly useful with it.

It's important to distinguish between the type of a *variable* and the type of the object a variable's value may refer to. For example:

```
object foo = Activator.CreateInstance(someType);
```

will end up with a variable of type `object`, but the *value* of `foo` will be a reference to an instance of whatever type `someType` refers to.

Comment: @jams: I'll see if I have time to add an answer later on. It won't be for a while though. The other answers look reasonable to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 var object = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from C# 3 you can do:

```
var someOtherString = "here is another string";
```

This way you don't care what's the type, `var` is type "joker" and save you the need to know the type at declaration time.

Hope that's what you mean?

Comment: `var` has been around since C# 3.0

Comment: Thanks @Bala, got confused with `dynamic` for a minute

Comment: The question is not clear but if the value assigned is null, for example, the type of `someOtherString` should be the same as the type of `someString`.

Comment: You *do* need to know the type at declaration time. You don't need to *specify* it, but it must be known. You're making it sound more like `dynamic` than `var`...

Answer (score 0):

use Assembly.CreateInstance()

```
Type type = typeof(String);
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
object blah = asm.CreateInstance(type.FullName);
```